# What Microsoft service handles file explorer functions, like copy pasting, right click on a folder

Tags: windows, service

I am using Windows 10 and whenever I try to copy paste some content in any folder, my system refreshes (reloaded) and file explorer window closed without executing the copy-pasting task. On right click on any folder, also refreshes the system and nothing happens. 
To my knowledge, some Microsoft service is causing this issue, don't know which service. Any leads, please?

I tried to run the system on safe mode with basic services and it works fine. On the other hand, when I disable all the 3rd party services and restart the system with only Microsoft's services, the same issue again. that means there is some Microsft services which are causing the issue.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

try to run Windows on safe mode, and enable one by one each service, spaced by tests, and if your poblem occur after enabling a service, I think you would find out wich service is causing your problem

And then, Google "(service name) problem copy paste Windows 10" and see if others have this problem

hope it help